# Add script to page from user control .ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

how can i add a javascript file to the page head from a user control?

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you want to do that? You could just add the JS file to the user control and it would work.

Comment: @Raja - That would result in that javascript file being included every time the user control is.

Comment: @Nick - hmm...makes pretty good sense. If it is used only once in a page then it would be fine but if it is used at multiple places in the same page then it would be that extra file being added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Page.RegisterStartupScript("pranay","javascriptFunction()")`

put this thing in you load method of user control

check this out :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.aspx

Comment: This will result in javascript file being included more than once if the control has multiple instance on the page.

Comment: Unless i do 

if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(type, scriptName))
            {                
                cs.RegisterStartupScript(type, scriptName, script, true);
            }

Comment: @ARS, that isn't true. The first argument passed into `RegisterStartupScript` is a key parameter used to identify a piece of JavaScript. Attempting to add a script with the same key will not create a duplicate of the script.

Comment: This doesnt add to the head of the document

Answer (score 0):

Are you using master page in your site? If yes then you should do all such includes in the master page. But then also  you might face issue with the path of javascript file. You can include the file in following way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Script/jquery.js") %>"></script>
```

If you want to do it from User Control. Try the following:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        ' Define the name, type and url of the client script on the page.
        Dim csname As String = "ButtonClickScript"
        Dim csurl As String = "~/script_include.js"
        Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()

        ' Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
        Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

        ' Check to see if the include script is already registered.
        If (Not cs.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered(cstype, csname)) Then

            cs.RegisterClientScriptInclude(cstype, csname, ResolveClientUrl(csurl))

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: I was wrong when I said that javascript file being included more than once if the control has multiple instance on the page. Hence updated my answer.